# Matching multiple conditions in an array in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I need help matching multiple conditions in MongoDB

```
{
    "id": "kul",
    "powers": [
        {
            "label": "a",
            "Rating": 7
        },
        {
            "label": "b",
            "Rating": 3
        },
        {
            "label": "c",
            "Rating": 4
        },
        {
            "label": "d",
            "Rating": 5
        }
    ],
    "phy": {
        "height": 67,
        "weight": 150
    }
}
```

I want to filter out records only where power `label = c` with a `rating > 4` and `weight > 150`

Comment: Hi, you could adjust tags, like add SQL, and explain what you tried already, I'm sure there are examples that solve that question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to use `$elemMatch`, try this:

```js
db.collection.find({
    "powers": {
        "$elemMatch": {
            "label": "c",
            "Rating": {
                $gt: 4
            }
        }
    },
    "phy.weight": {
        $gt: 150
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "powers.label": "c",
  "powers.Rating": {
    $gt: 4
  },
  "phy.weight": {
    $gt: 150
  }
}
```

Comment: It will check any rating greater than 4 not for the C only . I need to check the only for C.

Comment: it will check where `label=c && rating>4 && wight>150`

Comment: @MoazzamArif it'll check the conditions but not on the same element, it may verify label condition on the third element in the array for example and rating condition on another element which isn't what the question desire

Comment: thats right, i didnt keep that in mind :)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.